# Why my validation loss is smaller than the training loss?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder, loss

I am consistently getting a higher training loss than the validation loss while training a deep convolution autoencoder. Notice in my train data generator, I am doing data augmentation with Keras zoom_range. If I raise the zoom range like [0.8-4], [0.8,6] etc the gap between training and validation loss keeps increasing.
Is it because training loss is calculated on augmented data? Assuming more augmentation makes it harder for the model to predict(reconstruct) the input image. Or something wrong with my training method? I have attached my code snippet for the training command as well.

[image: code for training and validation generator]

```js
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(model_save_dir, monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=False, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

history = model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator, epochs=n_epochs, shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

[image: loss curves and zoom range]

Comment: Do you have l2 or l1 regularization in your model? That could also be a reason

Comment: at first I did not have and l2 regularization but I used l2 activity regularize in the first layer only. Did not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your train loss increase as you are increasing data augmentation effect and basically this is because it becomes harder for the model to learn pattern with too much data augmentation.
In my point of view the goal of data augmentation is to make realistic change from initial data to improve the model's robustness like a regularization technique.

However the loss of validation remains the same so I presume the efficiency of the learning phase is not impaired so much. I will have made sure that the distribution of the labels is homogenous and the data from train/val is stratified. I will also have made a test set (without any data augmentation such as the validation set) to make comparaison more valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely you made some mistakes I think. Remove your regularization and calculate your loss again. Check if your validation and training sets are overlapping. If yes, then clean up. The other possibility is whether your labels are correct. It happened to me before and took me few weeks to find out that my labels are messed up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).